# Implementing External Merge Sort

Tags: c++, sorting, file-io, merge

I am aware of [External merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting) and how it works.
But currently i'm stuck while implementing it. I've written code to sort and merge the arrays but I'm facing problem while reading and writing the data from/into the file, i want to implement the following methods in C++:

```
1. int * read(int s, int e) : This method should read from file all the number 
starting from 's' till 'e' and return the array
2. write(int a[], int s, int e) : This method should write to file the input 
array by replacing the numbers from s to e.
```

For eg.

```
Given file has the following numbers:

1
2
3
4
5
6

read(0, 2) should return [1,2,3]
write([4,5,6], 0, 2) should update the file to :
4
5
6
4
5
6
```

How can I implement both these methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you should do is stop working with raw pointers.

`std::vector<int>` will be just as efficient, and far less bug prone.

Second, the file format matters.  I will assume a binary file with packed 32 bit signed integers.

The signature for read and write is now:

```
std::vector<int> read( std::ifstream const& f, int offset );
void write( std::ofstream& f, int offset, std::vector<int> const& data );
```

`ifstream` and `ofstream` have seek methods -- in particular, `ifstream` has `seekg` and `ofstream` has `seekp`.

`ifstream.read( char* , length )` reads `length` bytes from the file at the current get position (set by `seekg`, and advanced by `read`).  If you aren't concerned with memory layout of your file, you can get the `.data()` from the `std::vector<int>`, reinterpret it to a `char*`, and proceed to `read( reinterpret_cast<char*>(vec.data()), sizeof(int)*vec.size() )` to read in the buffer all at once.

`ofstream` has a similar `write` method which works much the same way.

While writing data rawly to disk and back is dangerous, in most (every?) implementation you'll be safe with data written and read in the same execution session (and probably even between sessions).  Take more care if the data is meant to persist between sessions, or if it is output/input from your code.

Answer (score 0):

There are no C++ standard functions to jump to lines in files. So you have to read the file line by line (with getline, for example. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/).

As far as I remember, external merge sort (the old one, designed for a computer with a few tape drives), when used with separate files, doesn't need an interface like yours - you can work sequentially.

Comment: As Yakk mentioned, it is possible to jump to a line in a text file by using istream::seekg and istream::tellg functions. However, I am not sure about the time complexity and efficiency of these functions. 
See the example in the following link: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/